# Why the transition does not work if I change the style of a div after inserting it to DOM?

Tags: html, css, frontend

The code is simple:

```js
ground = document.getElementsByClassName('ground')[0]
item = document.createElement('div')
item.classList.add('roll')
item.style.transition = 'transform 5s linear'
item.style.transform = 'translateX(100%)';
ground.appendChild(item)
item.style.transform = 'translateX(-300px)';
```

```css
.ground {
    position: absolute;
    width:500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: orange;
}
.roll {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='ground'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expect it to be a red block moving from right to left, because I change the style of transform and it is the property that declared in 'transition'. But the red block just show up on the position of 'translateX(-300px)', where I think it should end.

Comment: If you apply the `style` immediately one after another, it does not "queue" the animation but the browser simply transitions to the final state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the browser sees you applying the CSS transform styles at the same time (aka within the same callstack). This causes the browser to "short circuit" and determine that it is the final layout that really matters, and ignores the `translateX(100%)` in the middle.

In order to force a transition, you will need to tell the browser that you want to perform the next translation at the end of the callstack. This will have the effect of forcing the browser to perform the first transformation, and then perform the second one.

An example to call something at the end of the callstack is to use `window.setTimeout()` with a delay of `0`:

```js
const ground = document.getElementsByClassName('ground')[0];
const item = document.createElement('div');

item.classList.add('roll');
item.style.transition = 'transform 5s linear';
item.style.transform = 'translateX(100%)';
ground.appendChild(item);

// Mutate transform attribute at end of callstack
window.setTimeout(() => {
  item.style.transform = 'translateX(-300px)';
}, 0);
```

```css
.ground {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.roll {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='ground'></div>
```

---

If you want a more modern solution, you can always use the async/await regime. This will avoid needing to nest timeout callbacks needlessly:

```js
const ground = document.getElementsByClassName('ground')[0];
const item = document.createElement('div');

// Sleeper function
function sleep(duration) {
  return new Promise(resolve => window.setTimeout(resolve, duration));
}

async function animate() {
  item.classList.add('roll');
  item.style.transition = 'transform 5s linear';
  item.style.transform = 'translateX(100%)';
  ground.appendChild(item);
  
  // Sleep for 0ms (aka push operation to end of callstack)
  await sleep(0);

  // Mutate transform attribute at end of callstack
  item.style.transform = 'translateX(-300px)';
}

animate();
```

```css
.ground {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.roll {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='ground'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JS for this simple animation. CSS 3 is fine.
This moves the red square from right to left -100px for the width of the square;

**HTML**

```
 <div class='ground'>
 <div class='roll'></div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .ground {
 position:absolute;
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
 background-color:orange;
 }

 .roll {
 position:relative;
 float:right;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:red;
 animation:move 1.5s infinite;
 }
    
 @keyframes move {
 0% {transform:translateX(0);}
 100% {transform:translateX(-400px);}
 }
```

Adjust your timing by altering the animation seconds.
https://jsfiddle.net/6hqn30js/1/

Alternative. Play anim once from right to left then stop on left.
https://jsfiddle.net/mpah37ty/

Comment: Thanks but actually I'm in a more complicated situation and this is just a minimized problem. In my situation the animation performs badly in Safari (It flickers!!)

Comment: Okay but you could still use the above CSS as a class to be added through JS when needed. This may eliminate issues with other browsers.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks so much. By the way, how could I change the keyframe at 100% dynamically with JS?

Comment: If you want the animation to play once just remove infinite from .roll CSS. Other than that if you are looking for something a user can control, I'd recommend an HTML range slider, which can also be animated if required. Added a new link to my answer for play once right to left then stop.