# How the items slide to the right continuously in css

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, slide

I have cards and I put some animation to them such as when you hover the cards it blurs the background and the colour is changing. What I am trying to achieve I want whole cards to slide to the right continuously and when one of the card items is hovered animation (sliding to right) should stop. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="about-section">
            <div class="card-grid">
              <a class="card" href="#">
                <div class="card-background" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557177324-56c542165309?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80)"></div>
              </a>
              <a class="card" href="#">
                <div class="card-background" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557187666-4fd70cf76254?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60)"></div>
              </a>
              <a class="card" href="#">
                <div class="card-background" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556680262-9990363a3e6d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60)"></div>
              </li>
              <a class="card" href="#">
                <div class="card-background" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557004396-66e4174d7bf6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60)"></div>
              </a>
            <div>
        </div>
```

And here is my css:

```
.about-section {
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 64px 24px;
}

.card-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 24px;
  grid-row-gap: 24px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 540px) {
  .card-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
  .card-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}

.card {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  filter: brightness(0.9) saturate(0);
}

.card:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 150%;
  width: 100%;
}

.card-background {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 24px;
  bottom: 0;
  filter: brightness(0.75) saturate(1.2) contrast(0.85);
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: center;
  trsnsform: scale(1) translateZ(0);
  transition: filter 200ms linear, transform 200ms linear;
}

.card:hover {
  filter: unset;
}

.card:hover .card-background {
  transform: scale(1.05) translateZ(0);
}

.card-grid:hover > .card:not(:hover) .card-background {
  filter: unset;
  filter: brightness(0.5) saturate(0) contrast(1.2) blur(20px);
}
```

Comment: You can't do this with CSS alone, you'll need JavaScript to control the animation. Through Js add a CSS class for animation then remove it when items are hovered/clicked.

Comment: But how can I slide the cards to the right? Can you help me giving some code examples for example/

Comment: I wrote a very similar answer to this a while back, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64031083/why-the-transition-does-not-work-if-i-change-the-style-of-a-div-after-inserting/64031417#64031417

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of animation and @keyframe.
Add properties in @keyframe {animation-iteration-count: infinite;  animation-direction: forward;} also you have to add transform property inside css.

Comment: Try formatting your code more properly. You should also include the transform property in your code, instead of telling to put it on their own.

Comment: I dont get it. How should I add it?